# How to navigate webpage history in webview

Tags: android, android-webview

I have webview included in my app. I want to navigate webpage history, but I don`t know how to do that. Please help me. My Main.java below:

```
package com.abc.test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class Main extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    WebView wv = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
    WebSettings webSettings = wv.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    });
    wv.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");

    }
}
```

Comment: did my solution not work for you?

Comment: don't call view.loadUrl(url); from shouldOverrideUrlLoading, return false instead.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code

```
public void goBackInWebView(){
    WebBackForwardList history = webView.copyBackForwardList();
    int index = -1;
    String url = null;

    while (webView.canGoBackOrForward(index)) {
          if (!history.getItemAtIndex(history.getCurrentIndex() + index).getUrl().equals("about:blank")) {
             webView.goBackOrForward(index);
             url = history.getItemAtIndex(-index).getUrl();
             Log.e("tag","first non empty" + url);
             break;
           }
           index --;

    }
   // no history found that is not empty
   if (url == null) {
      finish();
   }
}
```

Comment: I am trying, but I simply can`t make it works. I am new in programming, so I am still learning. Where exactly I have to put your code in? Thanks for answer.

Comment: same class just call it whenever you want to go back in history

Comment: actually it gave me error: The method e(String, String) is undefined for the type String; next to the line:  Log.e("tag","first non empty" + url);

Comment: remove  Log.e("tag","first non empty" + url);

Comment: I removed it, but it`s still doesnt work. Back button close my app, not go back thru website. Do you have any idea?

Comment: This might help you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20401155/goback-in-webview-goes-back-almost-all-the-way