# Android Webview : Navigation without reloading the webpage

Tags: android, android-webview

I want to navigate through a single-page website ( without reloading the URL ) that is being displayed in the android `webview`.

In JavaScript, there is an option to save all navigation URLs in history using

```
window.history.pushState("page1", "page title", "/page1");
window.history.pushState("page2", "page title", "/page2");
window.history.pushState("page3", "page title", "/page3");
window.history.pushState("page4", "page title", "/page4");
```

Thus I get the history index from 0 to 3. Suppose when I want to navigate from /page 4 to /page2. I will call

```
window.history.go(-2);
```

Same thing I read in the android `webview` documents and found these methods

```
copyBackForwardList();
```

and

```
canGoBackOrForward(-2);
```

But I don't know how and wherein the code I should implement it.

How `copyBackForwardList()` will be updated, if I'm at `/page1`. Should I have to visit all the pages (1to4) to update their history to this method. My requirement is that user can navigate to any of the page using `canGoBackOrForward(pageIndex);`

Please help.

Comment: Check if this link help you, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22515991/how-to-navigate-webpage-history-in-webview

Comment: @Prashant.J Thank you. How `copyBackForwardList()` will be updated, if I'm at `/page1`. Should I have to visit all the pages (1to4) to update their history to this method. My requirement is that user can navigate to any of the page using `canGoBackOrForward(pageIndex);`